# How to filter a table via a selectbox using angular

Tags: angular, event-handling

Given a custom table component as well as a custom select box component, I want to be able to filter the table rows by selecting an option from the select box.

My idea was to first add a click-listener to the options of my select box, so when clicking on an option, the `onOptionClicked()` method will be executed. Inside this `onOptionClicked()` method, I will emit an `optionSelected` event:

```
  @Output() optionSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onOptionClicked(option: string) {
    this.optionSelected.emit(option);
  }
```

My table component will react upon the event `optionSelected`:

```
<div class="tbl" (optionSelected)="filterTableRows($event)">
  <table>
    <thead>
...
```

There seems to be something fundamentally wrong with this idea, however:

1. My IDE shows an error saying `Event optionSelected is not emitted by any applicable directives nor by div element` .
2. The table does not react on the optionSelected event.

It seems the issue is that my table component and my select-box component are different components, apparently they cannot communicate via event emitters. Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding on the use of the `@Output()` [decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Output). This is something to be used to emit signals to other components using this one. You seem to be using it in the same component.

Instead, use a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) to retain your filter:

```
optionSelected$ = new ReplaySubject<string>('');

onOptionClicked(option: string) {
  this.optionSelected$.next(option);
}
```

To do the data filtering you could subscribe to the replay subject:

```
this.optionSelected$.subscribe(filter => {
  this.yourFilteredData = this.yourData.filter(item => { 
   // <-- you filter code
  });
})
```

Note: please remember to complete any subscriptions when the component is destroyed to avoid the common [memory leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject).